# If $g(x)$ is my density function, then $g(x_0)$ is simply $P(X=x_0)$?

Tags: probability, continuity, density-function

If $X$ is a continuous random variable with density $g(x)$, can I say that $g(x_0)$ is the probability that $X$ is equal to $x_0$

Comment: No. Probability is not the same as probability density.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If $X$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$, then
$$
P(X = x_0) = \int_{x_0}^{x_0} g(x)~\mathrm{d}x = 0.
$$
As $g$ is a probability density, the following holds:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)~\mathrm{d}x = 1
$$
So $g$ can not be $0$ everywhere, this means that $P(X = \cdot)$ and $g(\cdot)$ are never the same.