# Probability of single point in continuous domain is zero, then why for standard normal distribution pdf evaluates to non zero for 0.

Tags: probability

We all know that probability of a single point should be equal to zero. I am a bit confused , then why $f(0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$, where $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$ is PDF for standard normal distribution.

Thanks

Comment: For a continuous distribution, you get non-zero results if you ask for the probability that your variable is in some range.  For instance, the probability that a normal variable is in the interval $[0,1]$ has a non-zero value.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210630/what-does-the-value-of-a-probability-density-function-pdf-at-some-x-indicate
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3849959/if-gx-is-my-density-function-then-gx-0-is-simply-px-x-0
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720053/how-can-a-probability-density-function-pdf-be-greater-than-1
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4263617/the-probability-of-any-particular-value-of-a-continuous-distribution-occurring-i
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180283

Answer (score 1):

Because $f_X(x_0)$ does not show a probability but only a *probability density*.

Observe that $f(x_0)$ can also be greater than 1

take as an example $X\sim N(0;0.1)$

In this case you have $f_X(0)\approx 1.26$

The probability is calculated using an integral. The fact that for continuous distribution the probability of any point is zero is showed in the following way

$$\mathbb{P}[X=x_0]=\int_{x_0}^{x_0}f(x)dx=0$$